# How to remove the Special character in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, special-characters

I have used web service and get the response in the XML format, after that i have used xml parsing for parsed contents, but i get  Ä±: Ã¼rse  kÃ¼n etc., SO i want to remove that special characters and i have used NSUTF8StringEncoding and NSASCIIStringEncoding. But it doesn't work, so please give help me out?.

Answer (score 1):

Either what you have is binary data, or you have a string in some encoding that's not UTF-8. Assuming it's the latter, you need to figure out what that encoding is, which is entirely dependent on the data, what it is, and where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

**TESTED CODE: 100 % WORKS**

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"];

NSString *input = @"Ä±: Ã¼rse kÃ¼n";


NSString *folded = [input stringByFoldingWithOptions:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch locale:locale];


NSLog(@"resulted String is - %@",folded);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    resulted String is - A±: A¼rse kA¼n
```

**OR**

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"];

NSString *input = @"Ä±: Ã¼rse kÃ¼n vijay 12344";

input = [input decomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping];


NSString *output=[input stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"] invertedSet]];


NSString *folded = [output stringByFoldingWithOptions:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch locale:locale];


NSLog(@"resulted String is :%@",folded);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
resulted String is :A±: A1⁄4rse kA1⁄4n vijay 12344
```